# Adding formular fields to existing pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I already searched a lot on this topic but didn't quite get the answer I hoped for.

My Problem:
I want to generate fillable forms in a pdf file, which exists as docx and pdf in python.
The existing file contains a table layout and everywhere I want to place a textfield or an other control. I have the Name of the control in brackets.
For example:

```
Name: | [Name]
```

so `[Name]` should be replaced with a textfield.
I already read a lot about reportlab but I don't know if it can handle this (I think it can't read existing files)

Do you guys have had a similar problem and/or have any ideas how to realize this?

Comment: You should at least show your past attempts and explain why they failed. For example, you "read about reportlab" isn't enough. What have you researched so far?

Comment: I didn't try it out, but i read on their FAQ that it wouldn't Support reading pdf files: [link](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/faq/#2.1.5)
and i don't want to buy the Commercial tool.
That's one of the Problems beside the fact that I don't know if reportlab can replace the actual text with a textfield

Comment: It may be just a shifting problem approach, but, as a docx document is available, it might be possible to get it to OpenOffice/LibreOffice, which do have forms capabilities. You'd have to find out whether you can insert controls programmatically; if that works out, export the document to PDF, and your form fields will be there. You might have to do some fine-tuning of the fields in Acrobat.